# Changing legend for gradient scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have made a custom gradient scale in ggplot2 in order to visualise some data.

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

d=data.table(a=c(sample(seq(1,1500,1),20000, replace=T),sample(seq(1998,2000,1),1000, replace=T),sample(seq(1,150,1),19000, replace=T)),
             b=c(sample(seq(1,2000,1),20000, replace=T),sample(seq(150,160,1),1000, replace=T),sample(seq(1100,1600,1),19000, replace=T)))
ggplot(d) + 
  aes(x = a, y = b) +
  geom_hex(bins = 70, colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", 'yellow', 
                                    'coral2', 'red2'), 
                       values = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 1),
                       limits=c(1,1000)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: The graph]

The goal was to visualise areas where my data is very dense (let's say where the hexagons contain more than 100 observations, colored in coral2/red), while keeping a lot of nuance in the less dense part of my dataset.

The problem is : we cannot really see what the yellow and orange are standing for in the legend. I would need to zoom on a certain part of the legend, here the [0;100] area, without changing my color scale.

Does someone know how to do that ? I tried some things using `aes.override`, but none of it worked.

PS : This is dummy data. Here we can still guess that the yellow stands for a area containing <50 observations. However, in my real dataset, densities vary from 0 to 25000 observations/hexagon, so the legend is really unreadable.

## Edit : real code

[Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland)'s use of a log10 scale could solve my problem, but leads to an error message `Error in seq.default(min, max, by = by) :  from must be a finite number` when I use it on my real dataset. So here is my real code, if it helps to find where the error comes from.

```
library(tidyverse)

graph=function(.x,.y,legend.x,legend.y,title) { 
d %>% ggplot() +
 aes_string(x=.x,y=.y)+ 
 geom_hex(binwidth=c(10,10)) +
 labs(x=legend.x, y=legend.y,
      title = title) +
 geom_smooth(col="black",se=F) +
 geom_function(fun = ~.x) +
 scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("aliceblue", 'yellow', 'orange', 'coral2', 'coral3'), 
                      values = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 1),
                      trans = "log10",
                      limits=c(0,25000)) 
 }
```

If I remove the `trans = "log10",`, the code works. The same error is obtained when running the code on the example data.

## Edit : the result

Thanks to [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) (again) I could use the log10 scale. For people that have a hard time with the log 10 like me, you need to :

```
 scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("aliceblue", 'yellow', 'orange', 'coral2', 'coral3'), 
                       #Scales the values you want to the maximum value, here 25000, which is transformed to log10(25000).
                       # Here I wanted the hexagons that contains one observation to be white, that contains 25 observations to be yellow, .... 
                       values = c(log10(1)/log10(25000), log10(25)/log10(25000),log10(200)/log10(25000),log10(2000)/log10(25000), 1),
                       trans = "log10",

                       # Do not change the limits' values
                       limits=c(1,25000)), 

                       # If you want custom breaks, do not change their scale
                       breaks=c(1,25,200,2000,25000)
```

Hope that could save someone's time.

Comment: Can't you simply use a log scale?

Comment: No, I want to have direct control on the the scale I use : I have multiple plots to make according to the same principle and I want to have the same scale each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still say you should simply use a scale with a log transformation:

```
ggplot(d) + 
  aes(x = a, y = b) +
  geom_hex(bins = 70, colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'yellow', high = 'red1', 
                       trans = "log10") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
ggplot(d) + 
  aes(x = a, y = b) +
  geom_hex(bins = 70, colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c('yellow', 'red', 'black'),
                       values = c(0, 500/1000, 1000/1000), 
                       trans = "log10",
                       limits = c(0.1, 1000)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you, this could effectively solve my problem. It works really well on the dummy dataset, but fails in my real dataset (error message `seq.default(min, max, by = by), stop("'from' must be a finite number") `). I edited my post so you can see my real code.

Comment: Just replace 0 with 0.1 in your limits and breaks. `log10(0)` is not a finite number.

Answer (score 0):

We could set `breaks` like:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d) + 
  aes(x = a, y = b) +
  geom_hex(bins = 70, colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", 'yellow', 'coral2', 'red2'), 
                       values = c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 1),
                       limits = c(1, 1000),
                       breaks = c(0, 50, 200, 350, 500, 1000))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, that didnt solve my problem, because the scale is still unreadable, it only makes the breaks change. To see what I mean, try `breaks = 10*1:10`, that corresponds more to what I want to achieve.